# Next JS versus React. Which to use when for your Dapp?

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, react, dapp-design

This is a broader theoretical question. What advantages does a Next JS Dapp give over a React Dapp? Apart from file-based routing and an option to protect some code on the server side?

1. In case I am building a straight forward single page NFT minting Dapp,  a React site would be more than enough.
2. When it comes to retrieving blockchain data and displaying it, when would you use server-side fetching vs client side fetching? And why?

3.What if I'm building an analytics tool which allow each logged-in user to have their own customized dashboard with their own tokens/contracts/addresses that they wish to track. I assume a Next JS app would better suit this purpose? So that the user's custom choices can be stored somewhere and custom data for those tokens can be displayed? Or would this be easily accomplished with React as well?

**Any other advantages/ use-cases for Next JS in choice of framework for dapps?**

Comment: A better place to ask chatty, open-ended questions is [/r/ethdev](https://reddit.com/r/ethdev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every browser has metamask extension. By using next.js, when our code is taken and rendered on the server, on the next server we can reach out to the Ethereum network and do some initial calls like data fetching, or alist of items in your smart contract. we execute all of those requests on the server. That means when next.js produces Html documents to send down to the user browser, it does not matter whether or not users are using metamask. It does not matter whether or not they have access to an Ethereum network. Because we already take care of the data fetching for them. So all the users out there who are not using metamask are going to see some information on the screen.